# Passing a lot of different params into factory

Tags: c#

What is a better way pass a bunch of params to the factory. Not injecting them all to Class where factory is calling and passing them out?
I have abstract class with three implementation. And for each implementation I have two different http services and one db service.
I.e.

```
public class class1Implementation: someAbstractClass
{
    private readonly IHttpOneFirstService _httpOneFirstService;
    private readonly IHttpOneSecondService _httpOneSecondService;
    private readonly IDbOneService _dbOneService;
    
}
public class class2Implementation: someAbstractClass
{
    private readonly IHttpTwoFirstService _httpTwoFirstService;
    private readonly IHttpTwoSecondService _httpTwoSecondService;
    private readonly IDbTwoService _dbTwoService;
    
}
public class class3Implementation: someAbstractClass
{
    private readonly IHttpThreeFirstService _httpThreeFirstService;
    private readonly IHttpThreeSecondService _httpThreeSecondService;
    private readonly IDbThreeService _dbThreeService;
    
}

public class CustomWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHttpOneFirstService _httpOneFirstService;
    private readonly IHttpOneSecondService _httpOneSecondService;
    private readonly IHttpTwoFirstService _httpTwoFirstService;
    private readonly IHttpTwoSecondService _httpTwoSecondService;
    private readonly IHttpThreeFirstService _httpThreeFirstService;
    private readonly IHttpThreeSecondService _httpThreeSecondService;
    private readonly IDbOneService _dbOneService;
    private readonly IDbTwoService _dbTwoService;
    private readonly IDbThreeService _dbThreeService;
    
    private someAbstractClass myFactory(int condition)
    {
        someAbstractClass impl = condition switch
        {
            0 => new class1Implementation(_httpOneFirstService, _httpOneSecondService, _dbOneService),
            1 => new class2Implementation(_httpTwoFirstService, _httpTwoSecondService, _dbTwoService),
            _ => new class3Implementation(_httpThreeFirstService, _httpThreeSecondService, _dbThreeService),
        };
        return impl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a dependency injection container? That might give you an easier way to create your objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using DI container. To reduce code, you may declare `Factory` to be a [record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) class (available from C# 9). For record types, constructor with properties initializion is being generated automatically, so less code here.

Then if register it in the DI container, container will instantiate `Factory` object automatically, passing corresponded parameters according to registered types. An example with built-in .NET DI container:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public record class Factory(
    IHttpOneFirstService httpOneFirstService,
    IHttpOneSecondService httpOneSecondService,
    IHttpTwoFirstService httpTwoFirstService,
    IHttpTwoSecondService httpTwoSecondService,
    IHttpThreeFirstService httpThreeFirstService,
    IHttpThreeSecondService httpThreeSecondService,
    IDbOneService dbOneService,
    IDbTwoService dbTwoService,
    IDbThreeService dbThreeService) {
    
    public someAbstractClass Create(int condition)
    {
        return condition switch
        {
            0 => new class1Implementation(httpOneFirstService, httpOneSecondService, dbOneService),
            1 => new class2Implementation(httpTwoFirstService, httpTwoSecondService, dbTwoService),
            _ => new class3Implementation(httpThreeFirstService, httpThreeSecondService, dbThreeService)
        };
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging()
            .AddScoped<IHttpOneFirstService, HttpOneFirstService>()
            .AddScoped<IHttpOneSecondService, HttpOneSecondService>()
            .AddScoped<IDbOneService, DbOneService>()
            .AddScoped<IHttpTwoFirstService, HttpTwoFirstService>()
            .AddScoped<IHttpTwoSecondService, HttpTwoSecondService>()
            .AddScoped<IDbTwoService, DbTwoService>()
            .AddScoped<IHttpThreeFirstService, HttpThreeFirstService>()
            .AddScoped<IHttpThreeSecondService, HttpThreeSecondService>()
            .AddScoped<IDbThreeService, DbThreeService>()
            .AddScoped<Factory>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        
        var factory = serviceProvider.GetService<Factory>();
        var obj = factory.Create(2);
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Factory created: {obj.GetType()} object");
    }
}

public abstract class someAbstractClass{} 

public interface IHttpOneFirstService {}
public interface IHttpOneSecondService {}
public interface IDbOneService {}
public interface IHttpTwoFirstService {}
public interface IHttpTwoSecondService {}
public interface IDbTwoService {}
public interface IHttpThreeFirstService {}
public interface IHttpThreeSecondService {}
public interface IDbThreeService {}

internal class HttpOneFirstService: IHttpOneFirstService {}
internal class HttpOneSecondService: IHttpOneSecondService {}
internal class DbOneService: IDbOneService {}
internal class HttpTwoFirstService: IHttpTwoFirstService {}
internal class HttpTwoSecondService: IHttpTwoSecondService {}
internal class DbTwoService: IDbTwoService {}
internal class HttpThreeFirstService: IHttpThreeFirstService {}
internal class HttpThreeSecondService: IHttpThreeSecondService {}
internal class DbThreeService: IDbThreeService {}

public class class1Implementation: someAbstractClass
{
    private readonly IHttpOneFirstService _httpOneFirstService;
    private readonly IHttpOneSecondService _httpOneSecondService;
    private readonly IDbOneService _dbOneService;
    public class1Implementation(IHttpOneFirstService httpOneFirstService, IHttpOneSecondService httpOneSecondService, IDbOneService dbOneService) {
        _httpOneFirstService = httpOneFirstService;
        _httpOneSecondService = httpOneSecondService;
        _dbOneService = dbOneService;
    }
}
public class class2Implementation: someAbstractClass
{
    private readonly IHttpTwoFirstService _httpTwoFirstService;
    private readonly IHttpTwoSecondService _httpTwoSecondService;
    private readonly IDbTwoService _dbTwoService;
    public class2Implementation(IHttpTwoFirstService httpTwoFirstService, IHttpTwoSecondService httpTwoSecondService, IDbTwoService dbTwoService) {
        _httpTwoFirstService = httpTwoFirstService;
        _httpTwoSecondService = httpTwoSecondService;
        _dbTwoService = dbTwoService;
    }
    
}
public class class3Implementation: someAbstractClass
{
    private readonly IHttpThreeFirstService _httpThreeFirstService;
    private readonly IHttpThreeSecondService _httpThreeSecondService;
    private readonly IDbThreeService _dbThreeService;
    public class3Implementation(IHttpThreeFirstService httpThreeFirstService, IHttpThreeSecondService httpThreeSecondService, IDbThreeService dbThreeService) {
        _httpThreeFirstService = httpThreeFirstService;
        _httpThreeSecondService = httpThreeSecondService;
        _dbThreeService = dbThreeService;
    }    
}
```